# How to get text from specific element of any website using UnityWebRequest?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I dont know, how to use something like querySelector from JS with UnityWebRequest. I need to give some text from web elements, but I only have idea to sort this using the cycle. I must to have a way for automatically give data from chosen elements of chosen web-pages. I tried to use JS, but selector didnt work.

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class API : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string url;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(routine: SendRequest());
    }
    private IEnumerator SendRequest()
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(this.url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        string requiredtext = request.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log(requiredtext);
    }
}
```

So in this code I need to append selector of web element or something like this selector.

Comment: Well, the simplest answer would be you don't. `UnityWebRequest` just makes a web request, it's not a HTML parser/DOM manipulation library. I don't believe Unity comes with an HTML parser, and recommending a HTML parser for unity would be off-topic for this site.